# Custom Attribute Product - Checkout Page - Shipping Module - ObjectManager Instance

Tags: product-attribute, shipping-methods, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to get **custom attribute** from **product**, I've make 3 news attributes (width, height, length). I want get it to **quote shipping value**.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($items as $item){
$width = $item->getData('width');
//NOT WORKING
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added custom attribute on product level, So in this code you will not be able to get the attribute value because the **$item**  variable is a Quote Item Object and not Product Object.

You should be able to get the custom attribute value by this way

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $width = $item->getProduct()->getData('width');
}
```

Comment: Is not working, i need use something more? 
use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Soap\ClientFactory; 
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\Element;
use Magento\Framework\Xml\Security;

Answer (score 0):

Create a file 
 `app/code/[YourCompany]/[YourModule]/etc/catalog_attributes.xml` with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="width"/>
        <attribute name="height"/>
        <attribute name="length"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

and call it like this:

`$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('width');`

Note: You should not use ObjectManager to load any model directly, use dependency injection for that.